# module_invoke to create user search block not working

Tags: blocks, search

I've done the following to create two search blocks:

```
$content_search = module_invoke('search', 'block_view', 'content_search');
$user_search = module_invoke('search', 'block_view', 'user_search');
```

And I then call the blocks as needed like so:

```
<?php print render($content_search['content']); ?>
<?php print render($user_search['content']); ?>
```

They render correctly and the content search works just fine, but running something through the user search block just searches content. I noticed that regardless of which block I use, they both go to the URL http://example.com/search/node/[search parameters]

(This is Drupal 7 BTW)

Answer (score 0):

The search block only works for the default search type. From [`search_box_form_submit()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search.module/function/search_box_form_submit/7.x):

```
$info = search_get_default_module_info();
if ($info) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'search/' . $info['path'] . '/' . trim($form_state['values'][$form_id]);
}
else {
  form_set_error(NULL, t('Search is currently disabled.'), 'error');
}
```

The third parameters you're passing ('content_search', 'user_search') are ignored. Presumably your default search type is content and that's why you're being redirected to the content search in both forms.

You can build the correct search form pretty easily though:

```
$content_form = drupal_get_form('search_form', NULL, '', 'node');
$user_form = drupal_get_form('search_form', NULL, '', 'user');
```

Comment: How do I get $content_form and $user_form to display? I tried both render($content_form); and drupal_render($content_form) and both are blank. print $content_form produces the familiar "string to array conversion" error and print_r($content_form) does display the expected array data so I know the drupal_get_form call is working properly.

Comment: Yeah putting them through `render` is all you should need to do. Where is this code? It should be in a preprocess function, if it’s in the template file itself that might be part of the problem

Comment: It's in a block (with PHP code). Will that not work?

Comment: I’m not sure to be honest, it’s a bad idea to use the php filter for a bunch of reasons. I guess this could be one of those reasons. I’d recommend trying it the ‘proper’ way (hook_block_info + hook_block_view) to see if you have better luck

Comment: You mean as in a custom module?